# "Missing return Statement" but I already have the return statement

Tags: java, arrays

```
/*
 * One common programming activity is to find the minimum and maximum values 
 * within a list. In this challenge activity we will do just that. It will also
 * demonstrate how arrays and for loops compliment each other nicely.
 * 
 * First, execute the main() method as is so you can understand how the for loop 
 * works with the array.  If you must, set a breakpoint and step through the code.
 * 
 * Notice the min and max values are not correct. That's where you come in your 
 * job is to write these methods. Regardless of min or max, your approach should
 * be the same: (Here's the pseudocode for min)
 * 
 * set min to the value of the first element in the array
 * for each element in the array
 *  if the current element is less than min
 *      set min to the current element
 * end for
 * return min
 */
package minandmax;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MinAndMax {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );
        int[] array = new int[10];

        // Read inputs into the array
        System.out.println("Enter 10 Integers.");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Enter Integer %d ==>", i + 1);
            array[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        // Print out the array
        System.out.print("You Entered :");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%d ", array[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        // find the min / max and print
        System.out.printf("Min = %d\n", getMin(array));
        System.out.printf("Max = %d\n", getMax(array));

    }

    /** 
     * returns the smallest value in the array
     * @param array array of integer
     * @return integer representing the smallest
     */
    public static int getMin(int[] array) {
        //TODO: write code here
        int min = array[0];

        for (int a: array) {
            if (a < min) {
                min = a;
            } else {
                break;
            }

        }
        return min;
    }

    /** 
     * returns the largest value in the array
     * @param array array of integer
     * @return integer representing the largest
     */
    public static int getMax(int[] array) {
        //TODO: write code here
        int max = array[0];
        for (int a: array) {
            {
                if (a > max) {
                    max = a;
                    return max;
                }
```

I keep getting missing return statement and reach the end of file while parsing , however I already have my return statements and my code correctly closes brackets. Please help , thanks

Comment: Do you have return statements for *all* code paths?

Comment: The posted code cuts off in the middle of a method.

Comment: `"...and my code correctly closes brackets."` -- Not the code you've posted.  Try posting the rest of your code, and indicate which line the error is on.

Answer (score 3):

In your `getMax` method, you get the error because `return max` is not reachable if `(a <=max)`

Comment: In other words, do you have a return statement at the end of the getMax method if it doesn't hit the return in the for loop.  Even if you "know" it will hit it, the compiler doesn't know that.  It must return something if the condition in the for is not satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Looks at `getMax`, you have two open curly braces

```
public static int getMax(int[] array) {
    //TODO: write code here
    int max = array[0];
    for(int a : array) 
    {
        {    <===== HERE
            if (a > max ) 
            {
```

On a side note, you should not return `max` as soon as you encounter a number bigger than `max`, you should wait until you've looked at them all.

Answer (score 0):

If the if condition is not at all true, Or if the control never goes into the forloop, then the method `getMax()` will not return anything. but as per the method definition, It should return an integer. And there are few braces which are not closed/openned properly.

Try this

```
public static int getMax(int[] array) {
    int max = array[0];
    for (int a: array) {
        if (a > max) {
            max = a;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just think about what your code is realy doing in your 2 find methods.
you will never test all your int values in your array in that way you implemented this.

just test your values with a simple if(min < a) or if(max > a) and only return after your for() loop not in the loop.